# AWS - Elasticbeanstalk - Stucked on Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an instance that has "certificate" inside its load balancer. And this certificate has been deleted. So when I send new update to my elasticbeanstalk, its failed. And never worked again.

Because while building; load balancer returns error because certificate can not be found.

Then, I tried to change/remove the certificate from Configurations. But I can not, because "Status must be ready to make change". But my instance's status is not ready, because certificate is wrong!

Im stucked in a loop that; i can not work my instance because certificate is not exist, and i can not remove certificate from instance because instance doesnt work.

What should I do? How can I fix that issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ElasticBeanstalk then you should have a Saved Config template, right?

No need to fix the broken EB environment config (leave that behind already). Apply the necessary config/fix update on your template and deploy a new EB environment from the template.

As much as possible, EB environment should be always deployed/configured from template.